# issue with javascript set.has in lwc

Tags: javascript, salesforce-lightning

I'm trying to use set.has() in lightning web components and it seems to be not working.

Below is the code snippet..

```js
sStatusToVerify = 'Complete';
var setStatusVals = [...new Set(this.lstAllData.map(obj => obj.sStatus))];
console.log('setStatusVals  : ',setStatusVals);
console.log('Contains?? : ' ,setStatusVals.has(sStatusToVerify));
```

setStatusVals consoles all the values and it contains "Complete". However, the next console is not printed at all. It should ideally print **true**. Not sure why this is not working.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your solution is , you are converting the set back to array by using the spread operator `[... new Set()]` and array does not has `has` method . Hence the issue

```js
var sStatusToVerify = 'Complete';

var arr=[{sStatus:'Complete'},{sStatus:'Start'},{sStatus:'InProgress'}];

var setStatusVals = new Set(arr.map(obj => obj.sStatus));

console.log(setStatusVals.has(sStatusToVerify));
```